# Antonym of -proof suffix

Tags: antonyms, suffixes

-proof, used as the suffix to a noun, basically means that the object you are describing is resistant to the noun.

The specific example that led me to look for this was emailing our support team about a process we do that is not robust and highly prone to human error. I wanted the opposite of "idiot-proof", but couldn't think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Error-prone.
Idiot-prone.**

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prone) says regarding **-prone**:

> c. 1400, "naturally inclined to something, apt, liable," from Latin pronus "bent forward, leaning forward, bent over," figuratively "inclined to, disposed," perhaps from adverbial form of pro-"before, for, instead of" (see pro-) + ending as in infernus, externus. Meaning "lying face-down" is first recorded 1570s. Literal and figurative senses both were in Latin; figurative is older in English. Related:Proneness.